# ActiveMQ Connection failover detection for Spring bean initialization

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am trying to catch exception for an ActiveMQ connection which could not be established because of the broker being down.

With following code:

```
String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;                
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
```

The attempt to connect to the broker goes into infinite loop, if the broker is down. If I change url to

```
String url = "failover:(tcp://127.0.0.1:61616/)?startupMaxReconnectAttempts=2";
```

It makes 2 attempts and then throws an exception.(which is what I want.)

Now if I initialize the connection object using Spring Bean with the following:

```
<bean id="jmsFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL">
        <!--<value>tcp://0.0.0.0:61616</value>-->
        <value>failover:(tcp://127.0.0.1:61616/)?startupMaxReconnectAttempts=2</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I get an error message for failure to connect in 2 attempts but then, it still tries to connect again after every 5 seconds giving the same error message again and going on in infinite loop.

```
ERROR transport.failover.FailoverTransport - Failed to connect to [tcp://127.0.0.1:61616/] after: 2 attempt(s)
WARN jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'destinationQueue' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Connection refused
ERROR transport.failover.FailoverTransport - Failed to connect to [tcp://127.0.0.1:61616/] after: 2 attempt(s)
WARN jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'destinationQueue' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Connection refused
ERROR transport.failover.FailoverTransport - Failed to connect to [tcp://127.0.0.1:61616/] after: 2 attempt(s)
WARN jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'destinationQueue' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Connection refused
ERROR transport.failover.FailoverTransport - Failed to connect to [tcp://127.0.0.1:61616/] after: 2 attempt(s)
WARN jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'destinationQueue' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Connection refused
these messages repeat!!
```

I want to know how to stop this infinite polling and catch an exception (may be using PostInit) in case of failure.

Comment: when broker is up you are automatically connected. Why do you brother about this.

Comment: Basically I want to catch an exception on this failure and notify so that somebody can take an action to check why the broker is down?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement ExceptionListener in your listener class and override onException message. There you could handle your notification logic. While it try to reconnect automatically.

```
public class QueueListener implements MessageListener,ExceptionListener{

public void onMessage(Message message) {

}

public void onException(JMSException jsme) {

 // Send my notifcation here.

}


}
```